# Unexpected EOF from 'ls -all directory' - What could be the reason?

Tags: linux, docker, shell, ls

While building image with docker, I had to make sure that file copy has been successfully done, so I simply added `RUN ls -all command` at the end of Dockerfile.

The image build was successful on my local docker machine, but it has failed with this log on my build server.

```
Step 5 : RUN ls -all {directory_path}
 ---> Running in d575dd671675
unexpected EOF
make: *** [docker-build] Error 1
```

What can be the reason for Unexpected EOF from 'ls' command? I have no idea where to start investigating this issue.

+) I just realised that I was using -all for -al, but this can't be the reason, or is it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out specific node of my building cluster was consistently making an issue, I managed to remove the node and everything was fine. So, it was environmental problem rather than ls func itself.